# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel 4 and keep getting the same error trying to learn about some methods in DB class.

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
```

I get same erros trying to use "->or_where", "->order_by".

another problem is parsing the dynamic methods:

```
->where_name("test")
```

turns into

```
`users` where `_name` = test)
```

but if i try to do

```
->wherename("test")
```

then everything is fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're using an incorrect syntax for `orWhere` and `orderBy`.

This is the correct syntax for `orWhere`:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where('name', '=', 'John')
    ->orWhere(function($query)
    {
         $query->where('votes', '>', 100)
               ->where('title', '<>', 'Admin');
    })
    ->get();
```

And this for `orderBy`:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                 ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
                 ->get();
```

[`Query Builder - Advanced Wheres - Laravel`](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres)

Answer (score 5):

All methods in Laravel 3 have changed from snake case

```
->where_name("test")
```

to camel case in Laravel 4

```
->whereName("test")
```